# Do users update to the next version or the latest version?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Suppose my extension is version 1.0. I write a new feature and release 1.1. Then I quickly realize I've shipped a bug, fix it, and release 1.2.

Now suppose a user with 1.0 is offline until after 1.2 is released.

Will they update to 1.2 or to 1.1?

Do users get updated to the **latest** version, or to the **next** version from the one they have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users always get the latest version. So you’ll have to integrate any update code for 1.1 in 1.2 as well.

> Every few hours, the browser checks whether any installed extensions or apps have an update URL. For each one, it makes a request to that URL looking for an update manifest XML file. If the update manifest mentions a version that is more recent than what's installed, the browser downloads and installs the new version.

— http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate.html